# Javascript Array looks like its empty but has a value

Tags: javascript, nedb

I am a novice on javascript and starting to learn objects and arrays I just want to know why my array looks like its empty but when you click it has a value? See below code, I am using `nedb` and `Framework7`.

```
var DeviceArray = new Array();

db.find({}, function (err, docs) {

     docs.forEach(function(element) {

        $$("#listDevice").append('<li><a href="single/'+element._id+'">'+element.device+'</a></li>');

        DeviceArray.push(element);  

     });

});
```

Now putting the DeviceArray into a object.

```
    user: [{
        firstName: 'Jhon',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      }],


      products: [
        {
          id: '1',
          title: 'Apple iPhone 8'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          title: 'Apple iPhone 8 Plus'
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          title: 'Apple iPhone X'

        },
      ],

      devices: DeviceArray
```

Then when I try to check the object this appear.

[image]

The devices look empty but when you click it this appears.

[image]

I thought this was ok but when I tried to iterate the devices Array it returns nothing, so my question is how do I correct this? I already checked the `docs` output see below image, any suggestion would be great.

[image]

Comment: What does `docs` return, from `db.find`?

Comment: @ХристиянХристов see the updated question I included the docs output.

Comment: Its because of console.log is rendered before the data is populated. If i am not wrong, u should be loading data via ajax call. Its perfectly normal. To test, use setTimeout and give an interval 1000 or 5000 you will see the console.log devices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have recreated your scenario in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/1j4gu2f1/

There are two consoles, with and without setTimeout and both will give different representation on collapsed state but same result on expanded state.

I presume the code is self explanatory.

```
var devices = [];

setTimeout(function(){ //data loaded after 1000 ms
 devices.push({"name":"hello"});
 devices.push({"name":"world"})
},1000);

console.log(devices); // will show empty devices

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(devices); // will show devices array
},1000)
```

Comment: Yes I have, but still, working on `Framework7` since it uses a template for its pages I am looking to delay a load of these pages after all data has been pushed into device array, thank you for very much for that.